# record screen and internal audio with ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, ffmpeg, recording

What is the ffmpeg command to record screen and internal audio (on Ubuntu 18.04)?

I'll omit the many things I tried that did not work and skip to the something close to what I am looking for;

```
V="$(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | perl -pe 's/.* ([0-9]+x[0-9]+) .*/$1/g')"
A="$(pacmd list-sources | grep -PB 1 "analog.*monitor>" | head -n 1 | perl -pe 's/.* //g')"
F="$(date --iso-8601=minutes).mkv"
ffmpeg -video_size "$V" -framerate 10 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -ac 2 -i "$A" "$F"
```

I can get video but no audio.

```
parecord  -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  example.wav # index: 1
```

will get audio.

Comment: In principle, that looks good. If you can't get audio, first step is to verify you got the correct `.monitor` source. so `echo $A`, start `pavucontrol`, verify that the sink corresponding to it is the one that gets the sound. Next step is to verify that you can record from it with some other program, e.g. `parecord`. Next step is to try `ffmpeg` to record only audio.

Comment: @dirkt thanks apparently I did break a ffmpeg principle but I got it working now :) .

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/andreoss/screencast, it does pretty much the same you want, captures audio streams and the video stream separately, and than merges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Framerate applied to both streams, but since ffmpeg documentation examples are scattered I'll leave an answer here

```
A="$(pacmd list-sources | grep -PB 1 "analog.*monitor>" | head -n 1 | perl -pe 's/.* //g')"
F="$(date --iso-8601=minutes | perl -pe 's/[^0-9]+//g').mkv"
V="$(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | perl -pe 's/.* ([0-9]+x[0-9]+) .*/$1/g')"
ffmpeg -loglevel error -video_size "$V" -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -i "$A" -f pulse -i default -filter_complex amerge -ac 2 -preset veryfast "$F"
```

where

```
#A=1
#F=2018121711440500.mkv
#V=2560x1440
```

- `ffmpeg` the tool
- `-loglevel error` only print errors
- `-video_size "$V"` resolution of your screen (or less if you only want a subsection recorded)
- `-f x11grab` record the screen (screen recordings may not be possible on wayland?)
- `-i :0.0` the X11 screen ID, (can also add +x,y for offset)
- `-f pulse` the audio driver
- `-i "$A"` the id of the audio stream
- `-f pulse` the audio driver again (maybe not needed?)
- `-i default` normally the system microphone
- `-filter_complex amerge` merge the 2 audio streams
- `-ac 2` convert the 4 audio channels to 2
- `-preset veryfast` go light on video encoding to avoid stuttering
- `"$F"` the output file

Remember that the parameter order matters,
and `pavucontrol` can re-map audio only while ffmpeg is running.

Comment: That might be a stupid question, but why the second `-f pulse -i default`? Do you want to record from a second audio source (because the original audio is only about the desktop/internal audio)?

Comment: Wayland example; https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Examples-4

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f pulse -i 0 output_30_fps_fullscreen.mp4`

Note: change *0* (zero) in `pulse -i 0` to appropriate number (e.g. 1) if u get sound from microphone instead.